# On iOS, a button Action is not invoked if the main view has a UITapGestureRecognizer. How to make it work?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In a brand new iOS project using Xcode 4.3.2, if a button has an Action created using the Interface Builder, and it prints out `"button is tapped on"`, then all works fine.

However, when the main view is added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for a single tap, then even if the button is tapped on, the main view is thought to be tapped on but the button Action won't be called.

Is there a way to make this work?   (is it recommended to not use Button Action but use a UITapGestureRecognizer for the button?  But if it was a slider, then we do need the Action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the button in `[UIGestureRecognizer delegate]` or set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO`.

Comment: I tried and `gestureRegMainViewTappedOn.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` worked well.  Would you mind adding if it is `[UIGestureRecognizer delegate]`, how does the code look like? thanks.